# download rpivotTable output in shiny

Tags: r, download, shiny, pivot-table, rpivottable

I've found an interesting package `rpivotTable`.
I'd like to create `shiny app` which includes `rpivotTable` with the possibility to download generated data using `downloadHandler`.

However, I am unable to find the solution, how to create `data.frame` or something else which I'd be able to pass to the `downloadHandler` function.

`rpivotTable` creates an object of class:

```
class(pivot)
[1] "rpivotTable" "htmlwidget"
```

Is threne any possibilities to download the output of the this function?

Also, I enclose the example, how the pivot is created in shiny and the example of download function which I'd like to use.

Maybe are the any other ideas or suggestions?

```
set.seed(1992)
n=99
Year <- sample(2013:2015, n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
Month <- sample(1:12, n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
Category <- sample(c("Car", "Bus", "Bike"), n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
Brand <- sample("Brand", n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
Brand <- paste0(Brand, sample(1:14, n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL))
USD <- abs(rnorm(n))*100

df <- data.frame(Year, Month, Category, Brand, USD)



output$Pivot <- rpivotTable::renderRpivotTable({
 rpivotTable(data = df, rows = "Brand", col = "Category", vals = "USD", aggregatorName = "Sum", rendererName = "Table")
})



  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
   filename = function() { paste(filename, '.csv', sep='') },
   content = function(file) {
   write.csv(PivotOutput, file)
})
```

Comment: I'm the author of the package.  I'm a bit confused by what you are trying to achieve.  rpivotTable does not generate any data: it simply slice and dice the data provided. In your example the data to be downloaded would be `df`.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! What I'd like to do is to save those slices made with rpivotTable in data frame. For example i have Year in rows, Brand in column and the USD as a value. Is there a way to store this slice in a data frame or something like that? My aim is to export data which is sliced with the pivot

Comment: This is not possible.  Theoretically there could be a way. Nicolas has an example where the slice and dice parameters are sent back.  I haven't implemented this feature (I need js help!), but imagine if you could get back into R the latest parameters used to see the data, you could use them to filter the data.frame and save.

Comment: May I see this example? It would help me a lot!

Comment: I've just got some code and I will post this function and an example on github.  Give me a couple of hours.

Answer (score 5):

I've just pushed on the master branch of rpivotTable on github a change that addresses the issue of getting the parameters the user is / has looked at on the server side.

Download the `rpivotTable` code with `devtools`:

```
devtools::install_github("smartinsightsfromdata/rpivotTable",ref="master")
```

This is an example of how to get the selected data on the server side.  The example is not complete for your needs: you need to subset the original data frame with what you get back from rpivotTable.  But this should be enough to give you an head start.

```
library(rpivotTable)
library(shiny)

list_to_string <- function(obj, listname) {
  if (is.null(names(obj))) {
    paste(listname, "[[", seq_along(obj), "]] = ", obj,
          sep = "", collapse = "\n")
  } else {
    paste(listname, "$", names(obj), " = ", obj,
          sep = "", collapse = "\n")
  }
}

server <- function(input, output) {

output$pivotRefresh <- renderText({

cnames <- list("cols","rows","vals", "exclusions","aggregatorName", "rendererName")
# Apply a function to all keys, to get corresponding values
allvalues <- lapply(cnames, function(name) {
  item <- input$myPivotData[[name]]
  if (is.list(item)) {
    list_to_string(item, name)
  } else {
    paste(name, item, sep=" = ")
  }
})
paste(allvalues, collapse = "\n")
})

output$mypivot = renderRpivotTable({
    rpivotTable(data=cars, onRefresh=htmlwidgets::JS("function(config) { Shiny.onInputChange('myPivotData', config); }"))
  })
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(6,   verbatimTextOutput("pivotRefresh")),
           column(6, rpivotTableOutput("mypivot") ))
)
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I might have a go at a pivottable json export in the next couple of weeks.  Will let you know.

Comment: @timelyportfolio the actual output from onRefresh is a list(of lists) with the parameters, so the json conversion shouldn't be an issue.  On the other hand I wonder what would be the benefit of a json export for the OP. The missing piece to download the data as csv is a function that has as entry point: the data frame, the parameters from onRefresh, and in output the subsetted data frame to be saved as csv.

Comment: Did you find any solution for downloading rPivotTable?

Answer (score 2):

To extend Enzo's excellent answer (Thank you for the awesome package), I mocked up the following as a way to get the summarized data and use it inside shiny.

This uses the `onRefresh` to watch for changes in the config, then uses the DOM to get the innerHTML of the relevant element. In this case, then uses `rvest` to clean that html and extract the table, and finally, for demo purposes, shows it inside a `DT::datatable`.

This might be too hacky, but it can be straightforwardly downloaded as a CSV then, or passed to other shiny elements for further processing.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(rpivotTable)

FullPage <- fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput('aSummaryTable'),
    rpivotTableOutput('RESULTS')
)

FullPage
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(rpivotTable)
library(DT)
library(rvest)

function(input, output, session) {

  # Make some sample data
  qbdata <- reactive({
    expand.grid(LETTERS,1:3)
  })

  # Clean the html and store as reactive
  summarydf <- eventReactive(input$myData,{
    input$myData %>% 
       read_html %>% 
       html_table(fill = TRUE) %>% 
       # Turns out there are two tables in an rpivotTable, we want the second
       .[[2]]

  })

  # show df as DT::datatable
  output$aSummaryTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(summarydf(), rownames = FALSE)
  })

  # Whenever the config is refreshed, call back with the content of the table
  output$RESULTS <- renderRpivotTable({
    rpivotTable(
      qbdata(),
      onRefresh = 
        htmlwidgets::JS("function(config) { 
                           Shiny.onInputChange('myData', document.getElementById('RESULTS').innerHTML); 
                        }")
    )
  })

}
```

Comment: Great method @Shape.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A the github repository [rpivotTabletocsv](https://github.com/omargiorgetti/rpivotTabletocsv) I try to implement the export of rpivotTable to csv from a download button from Rshiny App.