# Not able to save the pivot table output as excel / csv from ShinyApp using rpivotTable

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button, rpivottable

I want to export the pivot table data as shown in the image in *csv, excel, pdf* form using buttons (**Note**: I don't want to export the actual data). However i'm unable to do so, can't figure out the reason due to my limited knowledge. Please guide me, I shall be really thankful for the help.

Kind regards

[image: need to save this out put data]

**My code :**

```
library(rpivotTable)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(shiny)

#ui
ui = fluidPage(
radioButtons(inputId="format", label="Enter the format to download", 
choices=c("none", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "copy"), selected="none"),

fluidRow( rpivotTableOutput("pivot")))


#server
server = function(input, output) { 


output$pivot <- renderRpivotTable( rpivotTable::rpivotTable( rows = c( 
"vs"),cols=c("carb"),vals =  "mpg", aggregatorName = "Sum",rendererName =  
"Table",width="50%", height="550px",
{
data <- mtcars

if(input$format =="csv") {
write_csv( data, 'data.csv')

} 
if (input$format=="excel") {
write.xlsx(data, "data.xlsx")
} 

data
}))}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214397/download-rpivottable-output-in-shiny

Comment: Possible duplicate of [download rpivotTable output in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214397/download-rpivottable-output-in-shiny)